# Fixed React Infinite Loop, but content does not refresh on successful item addition

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and am trying to build a simple CRUD app using an Azure Table for data. I had my code working where my fetch call would grab the data and render it in a component. I then had a second component for a form that submits to the table. That all works fine. The issue that happened was there was an infinite loop. I adjusted my code based on research and moved my fetch call into a useCallback. This stopped the infinite loop, but now when a new item is submitted to the table the component does not re-render. How can I get it to behave how it did without having an infinite loop. Code for each component is below.

Do I need to set another useState for updated data? Do I need to pass fetchData as a dependecy in the useCallback?

**DATA LAYOUT COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const AzureTableComponent = () => {
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      [redacted]

      const url = `https://${account}.table.core.windows.net/${tableName}?${sasToken}`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      console.log(response.data.value);

      
      setTableData(response.data.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  }, []); 

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchData]);

return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1>Azure Table Data</h1>
    <div className="row">
      {tableData.map(item => (
        <div key={item.RowKey} data-key={item.RowKey} className="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{item.FirstName}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{item.LastName}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
};


 
    export default AzureTableComponent;
```

**FORM COMPONENT**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TableClient } from '@azure/data-tables';

function NameForm() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');

  [redacted]

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    
    const client = new TableClient(`https://${accountName}.table.core.windows.net`, credential);
  

    try {
     
      await client.createEntity({
        PartitionKey: 'new Date().getTime().toString()',
        RowKey: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName
      });
      console.log('Data submitted successfully.');
     
      setFirstName('');
      setLastName('');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting data:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        First Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={firstName}
          onChange={(event) => setFirstName(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Last Name:
        <input
          type="text"
          value={lastName}
          onChange={(event) => setLastName(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default NameForm;
```

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'
import AzureTableComponent from './components/dataCards'
import NameForm from './components/submitForm'

function App() {
  // const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <AzureTableComponent />
      <NameForm />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Please also share code of the parent component where you render these two components

Comment: @ALTHAFPJALEEL Added code for component as asked

Answer (score 0):

I understood you need a polling, am I correct? If so, please try using [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) package.

`npm i swr`

```js
import React, { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import useSWR from 'swr'

const AzureTableComponent = () => {

const fetchData = async () => {
   [redacted]

   const url = `https://${account}.table.core.windows.net/${tableName}?${sasToken}`;
   const response = await axios.get(url);

   return response.data.value;
  }; 

// Please check the content of data if your expected properties exist.
const { data:tableData, error, isLoading } = useSWR('identifier', fetchData )

if (error) return <div>Error</div>

if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1>Azure Table Data</h1>
    <div className="row">
      {tableData.map(item => (
        <div key={item.RowKey} data-key={item.RowKey} className="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{item.FirstName}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{item.LastName}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
};
 
export default AzureTableComponent;
```

Comment: Potentially yes. I just want the layout to re-render when a new item is submitted successfully so that the new item shows without the need for a page refresh.

Comment: @OMGDrAcula `swr` has a polling functionality by specific time. As default, it re-renders your aciton like moving between tabs, click buttons or inputting text. See also [this page](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#revalidate-on-interval).